# configure error trying to install wgrib2 in mint: configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: linux-mint

I am trying to install wgrib2 from: https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/compile_questions.html

I have I am following the steps provided in the link, but when I run the last command `make` and an error occurs. The last part of the output is:

```
cd "/home/santiago/grib2/libaec-1.0.2" && export CFLAGS="-I/home/santiago/grib2/include -O2 -DIFORT -cxxlib -qopenmp -I/home/santiago/grib2/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/include -I/usr/include " && ./configure --disable-shared --prefix=/home/santiago/grib2 && make check install
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for gcc... icc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/santiago/grib2/libaec-1.0.2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
makefile:657: recipe for target '/home/santiago/grib2/lib/libaec.a' failed
make: *** [/home/santiago/grib2/lib/libaec.a] Error 77
```

I take a look to the `config.log` but do not get any clue on what to do.

```
 This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by libaec configure 1.0.2, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --disable-shared --prefix=/home/santiago/grib2

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = rossby
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 5.3.0-46-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #38~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 31 04:17:56 UTC 2020

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games
PATH: /snap/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2423: checking build system type
configure:2437: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2457: checking host system type
configure:2470: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2511: checking how to print strings
configure:2538: result: printf
configure:2610: checking for gcc
configure:2637: result: icc
configure:2866: checking for C compiler version
configure:2875: icc --version >&5
./configure: line 2877: icc: command not found
configure:2886: $? = 127
configure:2875: icc -v >&5
./configure: line 2877: icc: command not found
configure:2886: $? = 127
configure:2875: icc -V >&5
./configure: line 2877: icc: command not found
configure:2886: $? = 127
configure:2875: icc -qversion >&5
./configure: line 2877: icc: command not found
configure:2886: $? = 127
configure:2906: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:2928: icc -I/home/santiago/grib2/include -O2 -DIFORT -cxxlib -qopenmp -I/home/santiago/grib2/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/include -I/usr/include    conftest.c  >&5
./configure: line 2930: icc: command not found
configure:2932: $? = 127
configure:2970: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libaec"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libaec"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0.2"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libaec 1.0.2"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "rosenhauer@dkrz.de"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2975: error: in `/home/santiago/grib2/libaec-1.0.2':
configure:2977: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=icc
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='-I/home/santiago/grib2/include -O2 -DIFORT -cxxlib -qopenmp -I/home/santiago/grib2/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/include -I/usr/include '
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=icc

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL=''
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR=''
AM_BACKSLASH=''
AM_DEFAULT_V=''
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY=''
AM_V=''
AR=''
AUTOCONF=''
AUTOHEADER=''
AUTOMAKE=''
AWK=''
CC='icc'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS='-I/home/santiago/grib2/include -O2 -DIFORT -cxxlib -qopenmp -I/home/santiago/grib2/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/include -I/usr/include '
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W=''
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
DLLTOOL=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
FGREP=''
GREP=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH=''
MAINT=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE=''
MAKEINFO=''
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P=''
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='rosenhauer@dkrz.de'
PACKAGE_NAME='libaec'
PACKAGE_STRING='libaec 1.0.2'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='libaec'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='1.0.2'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP=''
VERSION=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='icc'
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot=''
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar=''
am__untar=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='pc'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p=''
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/home/santiago/grib2'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "libaec"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libaec"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0.2"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "libaec 1.0.2"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "rosenhauer@dkrz.de"
```

My system information is:

```
  Operating System: Linux Mint 19.3
            Kernel: Linux 5.3.0-46-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

EDITED:

add output `type -a cc`, `echo $CC` and `ls -Alh $(command -v cc)`

```
type -a cc
cc is /usr/bin/cc

echo $CC
icc

ls -Alh $(command -v cc)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 mar 28 13:37 /usr/bin/cc -> /etc/alternatives/cc
```

Comment: Post output of `type -a cc`, `echo $CC` and `ls -Alh $(command -v cc)`

Comment: Anyway - it looks like you don't have `icc`. Is there any reason you want to use it?

Comment: I added the requested outputs.
I only want to install wgrib2 from that webpage, the error appear to be related to icc but I do not know exactly what is it or how to solve it. And also I am not really sure that the problem is the icc.

Comment: »» checking for gcc... icc «« : Install "the gnu gcc" : `sudo apt install g++`

Answer (score 2):

Since you have `CC` set to `icc`, the `configure` script assumes that that’s what you want to use, and fails because `icc` isn’t installed.

You should either unset `CC`, or install the Intel compiler (which provides `icc`). If `icc` is installed but not on your `PATH`, `CC` should give the full path to `icc`.