# configure error trying to install wgrib2

Tags: linux, command-line

I have the same question as this: [configure error trying to install wgrib2 in mint: configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/582321/configure-error-trying-to-install-wgrib2-in-mint-configure-error-c-compiler-c)

However, I am not sure how to solve the issue. I am not overly familiar with Linux.

Here are the outputs from the same commands as the original post:

```
$ type -a cc
cc is /usr/bin/cc

$ echo $CC
gcc

$ ls -Alh $(command -v cc) 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     5B May 27 20:46 /usr/bin/cc -> clang
```

What exactly do I need to get the compiler to work?

Edit:

Here is the error:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/eli.turaskyriskpulse.com/Documents/Misc/wgrib/grib2/libaec-1.0.2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** [/Users/eli.turaskyriskpulse.com/Documents/Misc/wgrib/grib2/lib/libaec.a] Error 77
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The same error as the original post. I will update my post to show though for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is different than the mint Linux user. That
person was trying to use a compiler (icc) that was not installed.
Intel C compiler (icc) is not a generic name for a C compiler
that compiles code for an Intel cpu.

You are on a MacOS, and are having a problem compiling the AEC library.
You should try the real gnu C compiler (gcc) rather than clang.

See:
https://bovineaerospace.wordpress.com/2017/08/20/how-to-install-wgrib2-in-osx/

This advice is echoed by other installation pages.

Comment: Thanks for this. Solved my issue.